# User name recover from cosole

Tags: password-recovery

I have "The system is running in low-graphics mode" problem and I tried the recovery mode (Recovery Mode/failsafeX) and it didn't work.

It happened after and update

I searched for a solution and found the manual so i went with the (Ctrl+Alt+F1) for manual fixing

the problem is i don't remember the user "or if it is Case sensitive"

My question is: Is there a code typed in the console to recover or show users list of sort to confirm my username or if it is case sensitive ?

Comment: How did you log in after Ctrl+Alt+F1? If you can't log in, you can't run any commands.

Comment: didn't, That is my question is there a way to reach a terminal even from a boot-able disc to recover the users ? 
sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: See my updated answer for more help. You will need to boot into a live session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, yes user names are case sensitive. In general, in the Linux world, assume that everything is case sensitive, there are very few (if any) exceptions. By default, all user names are lower case so unless you have changed something, yours will as well.

Now, to list the users available on the system, you can do this:

```
 sudo cut -d: -f 1 /etc/passwd
```

If you are currently logged in, you can find out your username with

```
whoami
```

In bash and some other shells, the username is stored in `$USER` as suggested by Avinash but that is not always the case:

```
$ echo $USER
terdon
$ USER=bob
$ echo $USER
bob
$ whoami
terdon
```

---

If you have forgotten your username, this will not help since you won't be able to connect. The easiest workaround would be to use an Ubuntu CD/USB and boot into a live session. Log into your live system and mount the `/` partition of your installed Ubuntu. This is usually `/dev/sda1` but that will depend on your setup. If you need help figuring out which to use, edit your question and add the output of running `sudo parted -l` from the live system. Anyway, assuming the partition is indeed `/dev/sda1`, you will need to run these commands to mount it:

```
sudo mkdir oldroot
sudo mount /dev/sda1 oldroot
```

Once you have done that, get the list of users on the system with

```
 sudo cut -d: -f 1 /oldroot/etc/passwd
```

Alternatively, you can list the contents of `/home`, your home directory is usually the same as your username:

```
ls /oldroot/home
```